# Cannot access UIColor property of UIView from UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, properties, uiviewcontroller

Trying to set a UIColor variable on a UIView subclass from the main UIViewController.  I have a property for retrieving the color that is requested in the UIViewController and I have a property for the color to receive on the UIView.  However, when I use the dot method to apply the retrieved color I get an error "Property "brushColor" no found on object of type 'UIView *'"

//Controller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIColor *colorPicked;
    UIView *drawScreen;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *drawScreen;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *colorPicked;
```

//Controller.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize drawScreen;
@synthesize colorPicked;

- (void)viewDidLoad{   
    self.drawScreen = [[DrawingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 724)];
    drawScreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    drawScreen.brushColor = self.colorPicked;   //This line errors stating the property is not available on type (UIView *)

    [self.view addSubview:drawScreen];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

//View.h

```
@interface DrawingView : UIView{

    UIColor *brushColor;

    UIBezierPath *myPath;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *brushColor;

@end
```

//View.m

```
@implementation DrawingView

@synthesize brushColor;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    myPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

    [brushColor setStroke];

    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

you have declared `drawScreen` as `UIView`, change its declaration in the .h to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) DrawingView *drawScreen;
```

and change the ivar declaration to match (or remove it altogether since you're using properties anyway)